# Catalog Price Rule applied to wrong category

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules

I have set up only one catalog price rule. It's outlet discount, which should be applied to onyl one category. When I check in frontend, this price rule is also applied to some other product that not belong to selected category, but have same parent category. How can I set up rule, that will apply only and only one category?

The rule is:

> If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE:
>       Category  is  60

Answer (score 0):

Please apply the Catalog Price Rule this type may be help you

Please check the screen short :-

https://prnt.sc/rc0i3i

https://prnt.sc/rc0jze

And run the

> php bin/magento i:rei
>
> php bin/magento c:c
>
> php bin/magento c:f

Comment: My configuration is same as yours. But discount is also applied in some other categories.

Comment: your added the date??

Comment: Yes. Here is my config: http://prntscr.com/rdtgt, and rule still affect on some other categories.